# How to paginate the members list of a chat channel?

Tags: getstream-io

I tried to paginate the members of a chat channel using the **server-side authentication** with this request:

```
POST /channels/messaging/test-channel/query

{
    "members": {
        "offset": 20,
        "limit": 10
    }
}
```

But it's not working, it's still returning 100 members!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to pass `state: true` in the top level.

Otherwise, default response will sent and any related pagination will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Hopefully we get a more elaborated documentation in the future because there was no way for me to know this reading the current one.

Comment: Definitely or even better, it can detect state requirement automatically from pagination parameters.